# maven multi-module project execute parent after child

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

In maven multi-module project can we have parent project to build/execute after child?

We have custom plugin in parent that needs to be executed after child modules are build. Is there any maven life cycle that says to execute plugin after child projects are build ?

Comment: Why does you plugin need all childs? What will it do?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is: No, cause the parent is always executed first before any child. If your custom plugin needed to have all childs modules have been built you plugin should check this. Furthermore it has to be configured into a separate module which contains all other childs as dependencies to make sure the ordering is correct (Maven is doing this automatically).

And there is no such lifecycle cause the lifecycle is something about step by step but does not defined something about child/parent relationship...

Answer (score 1):

Create a "deploy" module, define your plugin in that module's pom.xml and put this module at the end of modules list.

Comment: Mind that the reactor build order does not guarantee that the end of the modules list is really the end of the build. Adding dependencies to all other modules may be cumbersome, though…